# Received ActiveRecord Relation, but need object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, lazy-loading

i've written the following classes:

```
class Occupation < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :pref_labels
  has_many :cv_occupations
  has_many :cvs, :through => :cv_occupations
  validates_uniqueness_of :uri

  # This function will return the specified label for the given language.
  def label(language = Language.find_or_create_by_code(:en))
    self.pref_labels.where("language_id = #{language.id}")
  end
end

class PrefLabel < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :language
  belongs_to :concept
  belongs_to :skill
  belongs_to :occupation
  validates_uniqueness_of :value, :scope => [:language_id, :value]
  validates_uniqueness_of :language_id, :scope => [:language_id, :value]
end
```

In my view, I call the following: **%td= occupation.label(@language)**
but this returns as error :

```
undefined method `value' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation:0x80c8368>
```

How can I get the actuall object returned instead of the relation? I know this has something to do with the lazy loading....

Comment: post also controller's action code

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change

```
self.pref_labels.where("language_id = #{language.id}")
```

To

```
self.pref_labels.where("language_id = #{language.id}").all #or .first if you only one the first one
```

Comment: in Rails 4 `.all` is now a relation as well.  `.first` still works tho